# Visual Studio 2013, New Project from local Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

My employer set up a bitbucket git repository, and I have cloned it via Visual Studio.

But how do I create a new project based on this repo?

Another example is an open source project, I want to commit changes, so I go to visual studio, clone the project.... And now I have a local repo but I still have an empty project.

How do I get at these files.

I basically want to create a new project, based on that existing project so I can edit files inside Visual Studio, then commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project uses Visual Studio then the git repo should already contain the project files. Since you say you're getting an empty project in Visual Studio I'm guessing that the project doesn't use VS.

If the project itself doesn't use Visual Studio then Visual Studio's git integration won't be much help. It's just another way of downloading the source code, basically.

To use Visual Studio with such a project you'll have to do the same things as you would after downloading any source: create a solution and projects, add the files, convert whatever build system the project uses over to VS, etc. Once you've converted the project to VS then you can commit the files you've added and begin taking better advantage of VS's git integration.

---

Most of Visual Studio's features rely on Visual Studio having a deep understanding of the project that comes from Visual Studio being the project's build system. If you don't want to convert a project to use VS as the build system then what you'll get from VS is little more than a text editor. If that's all you want then you can simply open the source code files in VS and not bother with creating Visual Studio project files.

Comment: [for a javascript Git project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27582798/553593) you can use the VS File menu to create a new project from existing code, pointing to the Git repository on your desktop.  Then you can use the VS tooling for that kind of project, e.g. for a package.json.

Answer (score 1):

I use the github app sync the code to the desktop and open the folder manually, you have the files in there